# Prime Algorithim Conjecture

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recursive-algorithms, conjectures

Let $g$ be the greatest factor of a positive integer($a$) where $g \neq a$  and $l$ be the smallest factor such that $gl = a$. Let $t_i$ be the $i$th term of the sequence where the starting term is $\frac{g_1!}{(a_1)^n}$ and $n$ is the greatest positive integer such that $(a_i)^n|g_i!$.

More specifically the sequence/recursive algorithim

$t_i =
 \frac{g_{i}! }{(t_{i - 1})^n}$

For example, when $a_1$ is $10$:

$t_1 = \frac{5!}{10^n}$

Here $n = 1$, so

$t_1 = \frac{5!}{10} \implies t_1 = 12$

Then

$t_2 = \frac{6!}{12^n}$

In which we find $n = 2$, giving

$t_2 = \frac{6!}{144} \implies t_2 = 5$

So here the sequence stops, as $t_2$ is prime and $g \neq a$ .
Its interesting to note that $n$ is the number of pairs of the form $a = mn$ where m and n are factors of $a$.

Now take a look at the number where $a_1$ is $14$,

$t_1=7!/141 \implies t_1 = 360 \implies t_2=180!/360^n$

You'll notice the explosive growth that it exhibits when put into the algorithm. This makes it seem skeptical this algorithm will always end at a prime number but consider the following:

Lets say we have a number $t_{i -1}$ with over $10$ factors after the fraction cancels out and each one has a very large prime factorization with many distinct primes in each. Now note that the prime factorization of each factor allows us to spread the primes across the other factors and combine them in many different ways. Lets say we had a function called $F(x)$ that determines the number of factors that can be possibly made from $t_{i-1}$. Then if we could prove that $F(x)$ at no point contains more than $y$ of $g_i!$ factors($G(x)$) such that $t_{i} > t_{i - 1}$ than there will be numbers of $a_{1}$ in which the algorithm will fail. But on the other hand if it does, and it can be proven that for some $a_{i}$ for any $a_1$ $F(x) > \frac{G(x)}{y}$ (In this case $t_{i} < t_{i - 1}$ is true) than the algorithm can still end with a prime.

Note that every consecutive term is co-prime and that we consider that a sequence terminates when $t_i$ is prime.

> Given any value of $g$ and $l$, where $a_i$ is not a perfect square, this algorithm always terminates.

Prove or disprove this.

Comment: So $\ell$ is the smallest prime factor of $a$

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: It's not clear from your description how $g_i$ and $l_i$ are defined. Is there an $a_i$? Is $a_{i+1}$ given by your $\frac{g_i!}{(g_il_i)^n}$?

Comment: What happens when $\forall n\geq 1$, we have $\frac{g_i!}{(g_il_i)^n}\not\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Yes $a_i$ is $g_i$$l_i$ I wrote it this way because I wanted to show $g_i$ as  a seperate part

Comment: and $a_{i+1}$ is $\frac{g_i!}{a_i^n}$?

Comment: @AlanAbraham presumably, then, one chooses $n=0$.

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed us at least one example of the first few terms of the kind of sequence you have in mind. If, for example, $a=8$, then presumably $g_1=4$. But what is $a_1$? (Is $a_1=a$?) And what is $t_0$? And how do you get from $g_1$ to $g_2$?

Comment: @Barry Cipra I have added an example, it should be clearer now.

Comment: @SpoonedBread, great, thank you. So if $a=14$, I get $t_1=7!/14^1=360$, in which case $t_2=180!/360^n$ with an $n$ to be determined. But whatever that $n$ is, $t_2$ is going to be extremely large, because it will have a lot of prime factors. Does that sound right?

Comment: That is exactly right and to help you understand a bit more $n$ is the number of pairs that are equal to $a$. ($a = mn$ would be $1$ pair where $m$ and $n$ are factors of $a$)

Comment: @SpoonedBread, given the explosive growth you get in $t_2$ with a starting number as small as $14$, I find it hard to believe the sequence will terminate in a prime except for a few rare starting values (such as $a=10$ and $12$).

Comment: @Barry Cipra I have the same skepticism as well but I want a proper proof of this if it doesn't eventually become prime

Comment: @SpoonedBread, I would recommend you edit your question to include a description of everything you know about when the process terminates (either in a prime, as it does for $a=10$ and $12$, or because it can't go on, e.g., for $a=9$ since $9$ does not divide $3!$) and why you think it might not terminate in general (as we both suspect for $a=14$), and then ask for help finding a proper proof.

Comment: @Barry Cipra the changes have been made take a look.

Comment: @Barry Cipra, please feel free to make any edits as you see fit I am not the best at explanations

Comment: @robjohn Thanks for the help

Comment: It seems you step is
1. Input any number a
2. g=greatest factor of a less than a
3. n is largest integer so that $\frac{g!}{a^n}$ is integer
4. If n is 0, stop, otherwise, set a=$\frac{g!}{a^n}$, continue setp 2

Comment: when the input a is large enough such as a=2x and input x is large enough
g=x, and g! includes a lot of big prime factors so that $\frac{g!}{a^n}$ must be much larger than a and it is unlikely the step will stop.

Comment: @Zhoahui du, unlikely is not a proof :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use symbol like
g(x) to represent the largest factor of x other than itself.
l(x) to represent the smallest factor of x other than 1.
n(x,a) to represent largest integer y so that $x^y|a$.
So SpoonedBread defined $a_{h+1}=\frac{g(a_h)!}{a_h^{n(a_h,g(a_h)!)}}$

The [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) said that there's at least one prime between integers x and 2x.
It has been enhanced according to the link that when x is large enough, there's at least one prime between x and $(1+\frac1{16597}) x$ so that there're at least four primes between x and 2x.

So when $a_1=px_1$ and $x_1$ is large enough and p is the smallest prime factor of $a_1$,
we have $g(a_1)=x_1$, and there're at least four prime factor $p_1\lt p_2\lt p_3\lt p_4$ between $\frac {x_1}2$ and $x_1$. so that $p_1p_2p_3p_4|g(a_1)!$, but all of them coprime with $x_1$ since there're larger than $\frac {x_1}2$ and at most one of them is equal to p.

Assume $p_2,p_3,p_4$ is not equal to p,
So we have $a_2$ is multiple of $p_2p_3p_4$ and we could write $a_2=qx_2$ where $x_2\ge p_3p_4 \gt x_1$.
Continue the step above we could find that $a_h$ is monotone increasing.

Comment: I'm struggling to follow what you mean by $a_{h+1}=\frac{g(a_h)!}{a_h^{n(a_h,g(a_h)!)}}$ this is not what I defined, could you enlighten me? I am unfamiliar with comma notation

Comment: @SpoonedBread, Zhaohui Du is using functional notation to indicate that the value of the exponent depends on the values of $a$ and $g$, and that the value of $g$ depends on the value of $a$.  So it's sort of like writing $f(x,g(x))$. My only criticism is that they are making the symbol $n$ do double duty, as both index and exponent; I would have stuck with your index symbol $i$, and written the superscipt at $n(a_i,g(a_i)!)$ instead.

Comment: I get it now thanks for the help

Comment: When you say $a_h$ is monotone increasing,  Its hard to understand as $a_h$ will become $a_{h +1}$ in the next step, do you mean to say that $t_{i - 1}$ is monotone increasing and if so, does that mean that $t_i$ is  monotone decreasing? Please clarify.

Comment: I think $t_{i-1}$ is alternative notation for $a_i$. $a_h$ is monotone increasing means that when h goes larger, $a_h$ goes larger too. That's $a_1 \lt a_2 \lt a_3 \lt \dots$

Comment: Okay thanks I got it now